# Python Replacement dictionary is only partially producing an output

Tags: python

I am trying to transform the output of a column which is currently like this:

```
    0        Q122 Your Voice - Energy Group
    1        Q122 Your Voice - Energy Group
    2        Q122 Your Voice - BGSS
    3        Q122 Your Voice - Strategy
    4        Q122 Your Voice - Strategy
    
    10265    Q122 Your Voice - Legal
    10266    Q122 Your Voice - Legal
    10267    Q122 Your Voice - Legal
    10268    Q122 Your Voice - Legal
    10269    Q122 Your Voice - Legal
Name: Survey Name, Length: 10270, dtype: object
```

The code below detects the first word and always keeps it and replaces anything else accordingly to the dictionary created.

The code below is produces only the `f{quarter}` part of the output but the `{replacements.get(key, '')}` part is not showing.

The code:
print(df.loc[:, "Survey Name"])

```
replacements = {
    "Your Voice - Energy Group": "Your Voice - E Group",
    "Your Voice - BGSS": "Your Voice - Services & Solutions",
    "Your Voice - Legal": "Your Voice - LRE",
    "Your Voice - Strategy": "Your Voice - SGBR",
    "Your Voice - Central Storage Line": "Your Voice - CSL"
}



def repl(match, repls=replacements):
    quarter = match.group(1)
    key = " ".join(match.group(2).strip().split())

    return f"{quarter} {replacements.get(key, '')}"


res = df["Survey Name"].str.replace(r"(Q\d+)\s+(.+)", repl, regex=True)
print(res)
```

with the output being:

The code produces only the `f{quarter}` part of the output but the `{replacements.get(key, '')}` part is not showing.

What I get:

```
    0        Q122 
    1        Q122 
    2        Q122 
    3        Q122 
    4        Q122 
     
    10265    Q122 
    10266    Q122 
    10267    Q122 
    10268    Q122 
    10269    Q122 
    Name: Survey Name, Length: 10270, dtype: object
```

What I should be getting:

```
    0        Q122 Your Voice - E Group
    1        Q122 Your Voice - E Group
    2        Q122 Your Voice - Services & Solutions
    3        Q122 Your Voice - SGBR
    4        Q122 Your Voice - SGBR
     
    10265    Q122 Your Voice - LRECS
    10266    Q122 Your Voice - LRECS
    10267    Q122 Your Voice - LRECS
    10268    Q122 Your Voice - LRECS
    10269    Q122 Your Voice - LRECS
    Name: Survey Name, Length: 10270, dtype: object
```

What could be affecting the output to only give the quarter part?

**UPDATE:**

this is the original output prior to applying the changes from the code. I purposely changed some of it when I originally posted the question.

```
0                Q122 Our Voice - BG Energy
1                Q122 Our Voice - BG Energy
2                Q122 Our Voice - BG Energy
3                Q122 Our Voice - BG Energy
4                Q122 Our Voice - BG Energy
               
10265    Q122 Our Voice - Corporate Affairs
10266    Q122 Our Voice - Corporate Affairs
10267    Q122 Our Voice - Corporate Affairs
10268    Q122 Our Voice - Corporate Affairs
10269    Q122 Our Voice - Corporate Affairs
Name: Survey Name, Length: 10270, dtype: object
```

Comment: Hi! With the data you posted I cannot reproduce the error

Comment: strange, would it be something to do with the actual dataframe (excel file) then?

Comment: Perhaps it can be related to the excel file. Could you share what you got if you add a `print(key)` before the return in the function `repl` and add to the question?

Comment: I've updated it, I tried to keep the actual dataframe different initially but it may be why I'm getting errors,

Comment: `Our Voice - BG Energy` is not in the keys of repl

Comment: so if there are survey names that I don't need to change or are not mentioned in the dictionary, the code won't add anything to replacement section to the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this `repl` function instead:

```
def repl(match, repls=replacements):
    quarter = match.group(1)
    key = " ".join(match.group(2).strip().split())

    return f"{quarter} {replacements.get(key, key)}"
```

Notice the change, now the line:

```
return f"{quarter} {replacements.get(key, '')}"
```

is:

```
return f"{quarter} {replacements.get(key, key)}" # '' was changed by key
```

**Output**

```
0             Q122 Our Voice - BG Energy
1             Q122 Our Voice - BG Energy
2             Q122 Our Voice - BG Energy
3             Q122 Our Voice - BG Energy
4             Q122 Our Voice - BG Energy
5     Q122 Our Voice - Corporate Affairs
6     Q122 Our Voice - Corporate Affairs
7     Q122 Our Voice - Corporate Affairs
8     Q122 Our Voice - Corporate Affairs
9     Q122 Our Voice - Corporate Affairs
10                 Q122 Your Voice - LRE
11                 Q122 Your Voice - LRE
12                 Q122 Your Voice - LRE
13                 Q122 Your Voice - LRE
14                 Q122 Your Voice - LRE
Name: Survey Name, dtype: object
```

**Input**

The above output was generated with this DataFrame:

```
{'Survey Name': {0: 'Q122 Our Voice - BG Energy',
                 1: 'Q122 Our Voice - BG Energy',
                 2: 'Q122 Our Voice - BG Energy',
                 3: 'Q122 Our Voice - BG Energy',
                 4: 'Q122 Our Voice - BG Energy',
                 5: 'Q122 Our Voice - Corporate Affairs',
                 6: 'Q122 Our Voice - Corporate Affairs',
                 7: 'Q122 Our Voice - Corporate Affairs',
                 8: 'Q122 Our Voice - Corporate Affairs',
                 9: 'Q122 Our Voice - Corporate Affairs',
                 10: 'Q122 Your Voice - Legal',
                 11: 'Q122 Your Voice - Legal',
                 12: 'Q122 Your Voice - Legal',
                 13: 'Q122 Your Voice - Legal',
                 14: 'Q122 Your Voice - Legal'}}
```

Comment: may I ask how replacing the ' ' with key changes the output?